# pgloader in centOS 6.7

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install [pgloader](http://pgloader.io/download.html) on centOS **6.7 (64 bits)**

---

## Steps

```
wget http://pgsql.tapoueh.org/pgloader/pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

---

## Result

> -Uvh pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm: unknown option

---

How can I fix it ? Did I miss anything ? Do I need to install rpm or anything like that ?

Comment: There are three supported versions of CentOS : CentOS 6 - 32bits, CentOS 6 - 64bits, and CentOS 7 . .... Please edit your post to include the CentOS version. -

Comment: It looks like you didn't run the `rpm` command (it wouldn't respond with "unknown option".  The `rpm` command comes with the OS and should be available.